# Template function to check if a smart pointer is null

Tags: c++, c++03

To frame the question, I had a macro that took a parameter, and called methods on it using `->`.

I wanted to extend it to check for null, but found that people were already using it with smart pointers, some of which don't support conversion to bool.

Some of these smart pointers have differently named methods for null-checking, and I don't have access to all the code that uses this, so I need a generic solution.

I was thinking having the macro forward to some template function, but I'm not sure how to do it completely generically.

Comment: Why have a macro that forwards to a function? Why not just a function?

Comment: Because it's a logging macro, to get `__FILE__`, etc, and to avoid computing log outputs when logging is disabled. Also I can't change it now (hence the question)

Comment: Would it be acceptable to write one template for the bool case and more specific ones for the "special" smart pointers? I.e. for each special method of validity checking, is there only one template or type? Otherwise I think some SFINAE will have to be used.

Comment: There's two smart pointers defined in & used by the library, but users of the library might use their own smart pointers, I was hoping for a _completely_ generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it is used with `->`, and that one works via `operator->` that returns the internal pointer, then perhaps you could compare it against `NULL`:

```
if(ptr.operator->() == NULL) throw std::invalid_argument("The pointer points to nowhere");
```

Ok, so if 'smart pointers' return 'smart pointers', we need to go deeper:

```
template<typename T> bool isNull(T *t) { return t == NULL; }
template<class T> bool isNull(T const &t) { return isNull(t.operator->()); }
```

Scary and effective (but needs a `const`-qualified overload of `operator->`.

Comment: This is interesting, but operator-> itself could return another smart pointer, right? I guess we'd have to recurse?

Comment: Then a templated function that compares against NULL plain pointers and goes deeper for other types.

Comment: Actually, is it 'safe' to call `operator->` on a 'null' smart-pointer?

Comment: Nothing is really safe on this planet. What is it exactly that disturbs you?

Comment: What I mean is, in practice, do smart pointer implementations produce undefined behaviour when you call `operator->` on them when they're 'NULL'?

Usually you're just using `->`, and then it's really bad to do it if it's null, but I haven't thought of it in this context before.

... I think our own smart pointers may have asserts in their overloads. ugh

Comment: Yeah...
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*
(which is also the page for `operator->`) says

`The behavior is undefined if get() == nullptr`